# SQLAlchemy How to obtain a response from Session query object?

Tags: python, postgresql, session, orm, sqlalchemy

I've worked through the [SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) and am now adapting it to my own database. I've run into an issue with the Postgres dialect where I am attempting to query the Session object, however I am not receiving a result. I am sure I missed something, and could use some direction in getting this to work, or at least what I should research. Thank you for your help.

**Code**

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, INTEGER
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TEXT, NUMERIC, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# CONNECTING
# create an instance of Engine, represents core interface to the db
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@ip:port/db', echo=True)

# DECLARE A MAPPING
# instantiate the Declarative base class for a catalog of classes & tables
# relative to the base class.
Base = declarative_base()

# map a table to a class by inheriting base class via declarative_base
class History_1m(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'history_1m'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(TEXT)
    symbol = Column(TEXT)
    ask = Column(NUMERIC)
    bid = Column(NUMERIC)

# CREATE A SCHEMA
# using the engine, create our table via a method of the MetaData registry
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# CREATE AN INSTANCE OF MAPPED CLASS
# instantiate an instance of the User class and generate attribute values
symbol_data = History_1m()

# CREATING A SESSION
# define a Session class to talk with our db
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
# in case of no engine yet, Session = sessionmaker() is acceptable
# to talk to the db you should use session = Session each time

# query the Session to verify the instance is pending
symbol = 'AAPL'
recent_symbol = session.query(History_1m).filter_by(symbol=symbol).first()

# print the contents of our_user, ed_user is our_user via identity map
print('\n> Do we have a symbol entry?\n', recent_symbol)
for row in session.query(History_1m).order_by(History_1m.id):
    print(row.name, row.symbol, row.ask, row.bid)
```

**Traceback**

```
Microsoft Corporation MSFT 65.52 65.51
Adobe Systems Incorporated ADBE 131.85 131.83
Cytori Therapeutics Inc CYTX 1.04 1.03
Whole Foods Market, Inc. WFM 35.58 35.57
None None None None
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It is unclear where you are getting your `NameError`. Your example should not produce it. Please include both a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the traceback you get. Or rewrite your title and question. As to getting `None`, are you sure that your DB contains a row for which `name = 'AAPL'`, or did you mean to `filter_by(symbol=symbol)`? Are you connecting to correct DB?

Comment: Hi Ilja, I've retitled the question and changed the Output section to Traceback. I know I am connecting to the correct database. I believe you are correct where I am looking for a symbol and not a name field.

Comment: Do I have to create an instance of the mapped class for symbol_data prior to adding it to the session and querying on it? If so, is there a simple way to do so where it will map to all columns in the table as opposed to implicitly defining them in the symbol_data object? (If this even is the issue.)

Comment: The code is now outputting all entries in the History_1m table. I am querying the session for all rows of History_1m with session.query(History_1m), but when I try to replace with recent_symbol, I throw errors. How do I query for just recent_symbol without loading all the rows in the table into the session?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "Do I have to create an instance of the mapped class for symbol_data prior to adding it to the session and querying on it?", and `symbol_data = History_1m()` is redundant as you don't add it to a session. It's just a new unused instance of `History_1m` class bound to name *symbol_data*, nothing special. A traceback is the output you get along with exceptions and contains the stack trace etc. I asked for it since your original title hinted at an exception. The problem with your original query was just the wrong column (name vs. symbol), apparently.

Comment: All in all I think you should read the tutorial again carefully, as you seem to be a bit confused about terminology and what is what.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean about symbol_data being redundant. I am continuing to review the docs and making good progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get the code working. I was not properly formatting the query object on the session.

**CODE**

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, INTEGER
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TEXT, NUMERIC, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# CONNECTING
# create an instance of Engine, represents core interface to the db
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@ip:pport/database', echo=True)

# DECLARE A MAPPING
# instantiate the Declarative base class for a catalog of classes & tables
# relative to the base class.
Base = declarative_base()

# map a table to a class by inheriting base class via declarative_base
class History_1m(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'history_1m'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(TEXT)
    symbol = Column(TEXT)
    ask = Column(NUMERIC)
    bid = Column(NUMERIC)

# CREATE A SCHEMA
# using the engine, create our table via a method of the MetaData registry
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# CREATING A SESSION
# define a Session class to talk with our db
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
# in case of no engine yet, Session = sessionmaker() is acceptable
# to talk to the db you should use session = Session each time

# query the Session for the first symbol entry
session = Session()
symbol = 'AAPL'
recent_symbol = session.query(History_1m).filter_by(symbol=symbol).first()

# print the contents of the response via identity map
print('\n> Do we have a symbol entry?\n', recent_symbol.name, recent_symbol.symbol,
      recent_symbol.ask, recent_symbol.bid)
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\envs\python36_learning\python.exe D:/tech_indicators/sqla_orm_adapt.py
2017-04-20 12:45:33,470 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select version()
2017-04-20 12:45:33,470 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-20 12:45:33,471 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select current_schema()
2017-04-20 12:45:33,471 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-20 12:45:33,472 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2017-04-20 12:45:33,472 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-20 12:45:33,473 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2017-04-20 12:45:33,473 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-20 12:45:33,473 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2017-04-20 12:45:33,473 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2017-04-20 12:45:33,474 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) and relname=%(name)s
2017-04-20 12:45:33,474 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'name': 'history_1m'}
2017-04-20 12:45:33,476 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-04-20 12:45:33,476 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT history_1m.id AS history_1m_id, history_1m.name AS history_1m_name, history_1m.symbol AS history_1m_symbol, history_1m.ask AS history_1m_ask, history_1m.bid AS history_1m_bid 
FROM history_1m 
WHERE history_1m.symbol = %(symbol_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
2017-04-20 12:45:33,477 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'symbol_1': 'AAPL', 'param_1': 1}

> Do we have a symbol entry?
 Apple Inc. AAPL 141.08 141.07

Process finished with exit code 0
```